# How to Write Sql RawQuery in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a query which is working in Sqlite Browse but when I write same in Android it is not working properly. Below is the SQL query I have written

```
SELECT value 
FROM current_tab 
WHERE variable = 'currentVehicleSpeed' 
  AND ABS(1 - value) = (SELECT MIN(ABS(1 - value)) 
                        FROM current_tab 
                        WHERE variable = 'currentVehicleSpeed' 
                          AND ABS(1 - value) <= 5)
```

I want above query inside `db.rawQuery(...)`.

This is how I have done it:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM current_tab WHERE variable = '" + var + "' AND ABS( '"
                        + valueDouble + "' - value )=(SELECT MIN(ABS( '"
                        + valueDouble + "' - value )) FROM current_tab WHERE variable = '" + var + "') AND ABS( '" + valueDouble + "' - value <=5) ", null);
```

where 'value' and 'variable' are the column name

`current_tab` is the table name

```
var = "currentVehicleSpeed" and valueDouble = 1
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working properly"? It select wrong rows, it doesn't select anything, it throws an error? Could you please post the query generated by your code?

Comment: it doesn't select any row.it is not giving any error

Comment: You don't have to use literal delimiters (**'**) on numbers!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to use literal delimiters (**'**) on numbers:

Your correct query:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM current_tab WHERE variable = " + var + " AND ABS("
    + valueDouble + " - value) = (SELECT MIN(ABS("
    + valueDouble + " - value)) FROM current_tab WHERE variable = " + var + ") AND ABS(" + valueDouble + " - value <= 5)", null);
```

Comment: Downvoter, mind to explain?! My answer is **correct** and answers the OP question!!

Comment: Tell it to who downvoted my answer... And while you are at it, please accept my answer, if it helped. ;)

Comment: (Not downvoter) While it's true that one doesn't have to use quotes for numbers, it shouldn't matter here. String literals get automatically converted to numbers if needed. If this solved OP's problem, the problem was likely somewhere else.

Comment: `Thank you for your answer :) its working fine now..` makes me think I'm not all wrong when I say that `stringField = 'ABC'` and `intField = 220`, and most importantly when there are arithmetical operations on numbers, such as `intField = ((110 * 2) / 4) - 55`. I wouldn't rely on SQLite "automagical" type conversions. Different story is for bound fields in a rawQuery() or execSQL(). But that's Android's Java implementation.